# Twilio - getting ERROR : Account SID cannot be null when making a call

Tags: android, twilio

I am getting this exception sometimes when app remains active for long time.
Could any one tell,whats the problem ?

Connecting call failed

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Account SID cannot be null when making a call
                                                          at com.twilio.client.impl.MakeCallCommand.<init>(MakeCallCommand.java:33)
                                                          at com.twilio.client.impl.CallControlManager.makeCall(CallControlManager.java:423)
                                                          at com.twilio.client.impl.InternalConnectionImpl.connect(InternalConnectionImpl.java:212)
                                                          at com.twilio.client.impl.DeviceImpl$2.onCompletion(DeviceImpl.java:339)
                                                          at com.twilio.client.impl.MediaManager.onPlayComplete(MediaManager.java:279)
                                                          at com.twilio.client.impl.MediaManager.queueSound(MediaManager.java:173)
                                                          at com.twilio.client.impl.DeviceImpl.connect(DeviceImpl.java:335)
                                                          at com.lola.activities.CallingActivity.connect(CallingActivity.java:199)
                                                          at com.lola.activities.CallingActivity.onCreate(CallingActivity.java:92)
                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT : ** here is connect() method called when Call Button is clicked :

```
public void connect(String fromMobileNo, String phoneNumber)
    {

        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

        parameters.put("frommobileno", fromMobileNo);
        parameters.put("mobileno",  phoneNumber);

        Log.d("parameters", parameters + "");
        Log.d(TAG, "device :" + device);
        Log.d(TAG, "device :" + device);

        if(device == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry from our side.Please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        else{
            connection = device.connect(parameters, (Controller)getApplication()/* ConnectionListener */);

            if (connection == null && ((Controller)getApplication()).basicConnectionListener != null)
                ((Controller)getApplication()).basicConnectionListener.onConnectionFailedConnecting(new Exception("Couldn't create new connection"));

        }

        if (connection != null){
            Controller.setConnection(connection);


        }else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code to make us solve this

Comment: @IjasAhamed have a look on connect mthod

Comment: @IjasAhamed I had made an Application class implemented with InitListener,DeivceListener and ConnectionListener.

Comment: Whats in com.lola.activities.CallingActivity.connect.java line 199

Comment: connection = device.connect(parameters, (Controller)getApplication()/* ConnectionListener */);

Comment: Did you get capability token? If its null, you cannot call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Twilio make a call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472521/android-twilio-make-a-call) Please also read [the manual](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/rest/initiating-calls)

Comment: @RC. No, my requirements are lot different

Comment: @YogeshSeralia You can make call when you start app. You cannot make when you use app after a long active time. Thats your issue? Right?

Comment: Yes @ijas you are right

Comment: Is this issue resolved ?

Comment: @IjasAhamedN : I am using https://www.ipragmatech.com/steps-make-call-android-twilio-voice/
this link for voice .... and getting the same error as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capability token has a life time. Its gets expired after it. I think, this issue is with expiration of your capability token.

So **update your capability token** to solve this issue.

[Check out this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/Device#updateCapabilityToken_String_)

***Follow below steps to overcome this problem***

**Step 1** : First try to check the state of your device before making out calls.

[Check device state](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/Device#getState__)

**Step 2** : If your device is **OFFLINE**, try to update token. If **READY**, call. If **BUSY**, dont call.

[Device State Values](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/Device.State#OFFLINE)

Answer (score 1):

#### C# Users

Setup your TWILIO credentials as environment variables.

Check here : [Add environment variables Windows](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html)

Call them as follow :

```
    string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
    string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
```

Then execute the program.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use [this](https://www.twilio.com/console) twilio console for your account sid and auth token instead of [this](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/voice/getting-started)!

[Edit]:
The second link is the old twilio user panel which I think is being redirected to the new one from exactly the date that I am editing this answer(!) which is the first link in above.
retrying getting new account sid and the auth token again using the new user panel control(www.twilio.com/console) solved the problem for me.